# reading graphml format file

Tags: r, igraph, graphml

I have a dataset of a weighted network which has a graphml format. I used below function to read it in R using "igraph" package, but it did not get the data's weight. Any idea to help?

```
net1<-read.graph("text.graphml", format = "graphml")
```

Comment: Where are the weights stored in your GraphML file?

Comment: A question that allows a reproducible answer would be nice.

Answer (score -2):

Based on http://igraph.org/r/doc/read_graph.html, you might like to change it to

net1<-read.graph("text.graphml", format = "gml")

Comment: Based on the documentation, `net1<-read.graph("text.graphml", format = "graphml")` is completely correct.

Original documentation (2018):
`read_graph(file, format = c("edgelist", "pajek", "ncol", "lgl", "graphml",
  "dimacs", "graphdb", "gml", "dl"), ...)`